# Do XML drawables support theme attributes?

Tags: android, xml, themes

I have a XML drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="?attr/img_chat_sendbar_more"></bitmap>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="?attr/color_transparent_icon"></solid>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="?attr/img_chat_sendbar_more"></bitmap>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In this drawable I use the theme attribute 'img_chat_sendbar_more',it defined like this：

```
<attr name="img_chat_sendbar_more" format="reference"/>
```

and used in the theme like：

```
<item name="img_chat_sendbar_more">@mipmap/chat_sendbar_more</item>
```

But when app run it crashed and output the 'Error inflating class' error
 like:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/chat_sendbar_ok.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020045
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2091)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:619)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:63)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:59)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:802)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:832)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:172)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at pj.mobile.app.wewe.view.communication.Fragment_Chat.onCreateView(Fragment_Chat.java:106)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1078)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <bitmap> requires a valid src attribute
            at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:490)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:901)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:183)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:901)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:837)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2087)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:619)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:63)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:59)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:802)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:832)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:172)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at pj.mobile.app.wewe.view.communication.Fragment_Chat.onCreateView(Fragment_Chat.java:106)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1078)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

However,when I user the drawable resource directly instead of the theme attributes, it runs OK.So I have a question that do XML drawables support theme attributes?

Answer (score 0):

The styles.xml or "theme feature" is designed to customize the appearance of android widgets/views, such as: `TextView`, `EditView`, `RecyclerView` and so on. 
On the other hand a drawable XML is a drawable resource(just like a png) and not a view.
In other words:

> No, drawable xml can not be themed by using styles.xml like other
>   android views, since it's a resource.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!Just now I found that it runs well in Android 5.0 but crashed in 4.4...So I think that is it because of the Android  Version?